# Scope of a variable inside a function in R

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
a <- 10
b <- 3
c <- 4
addme <- function(a,b) {
  delta = a + b + c
  return(delta)
}
addme(a,b)
```

It returns 17, but I don't understand why if variable `c` is not defined inside the function, shouldn't it be just 0 and return 13? Why it takes the value outside the function?

I have read some text about scopes, environments and global assignments with `<-` but I don't find something related to variables inside a function.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it checks for 'c' in that env first, then the parent env,  until it gets to the global env

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Just a question, is there a way to make the variables explicit inside a function, so it returns me "error" in the function I defined?

Comment: I guess Allan's answer would help you.  For throwing errors, you could capture the arguments wiith `match.call` and create a `stopifnot` based on that

Comment: I see, let me investigate further on `match.call` as you suggest. Thank you Akrun!

Comment: *"shouldn't it be just 0 and return 13?"* is bad intuition. Objects that aren't defined are `NULL`, not 0, and trying to add something that's not defined should be an "object not found" error, like `1 + aksjjdflskj` gives `Error: object 'aksffdflskj' not found`. *However*, in this case you've used the name `c` which also happens to be a function name, so if you do `1 + c` in a fresh R session you'll see `Error in 1 + c : non-numeric argument to binary operator` because you can't add `1` to a function. It can be nice to avoid using names of very common functions for your variables.

Comment: Hello @GregorThomas, you are right, since `c` is not defined it's like adding `10+3+NULL` so yes, it was bad intuition. To my amazement, `c` is a function I use every day to create a vector and as you pointed it's better to avoid that name in a variable. I'll be prone to find those sometimes simple (but avoidable) variables on the books and code from now on

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid the super-common function names as object names like `c`, but I don't worry about it too much. (`data` is a good object name, despite being a function). The key is to be able to decode those error messages and realize that a "non-numeric argument" might be a function.

Comment: @Manu, `environment(addme) <- emptyenv()` will make it unable to find `c` outside of `addme` but then it won't be able to find `+` either because it uses the same search strategy to look for functions.  If you are trying to find all the variables (but not functions) referenced in a function try `all.vars(body(addme))`

Comment: It's difficult to see why you would want the function to throw an error if it tries to use a variable that it hasn't itself declared inside the function body. Why would you purposefully write a function that tries to use an undeclared variable? If you somehow had a conditionally-created variable `c` inside the function and you wanted to ensure it was _that_ variable you were using you could do `c <- environment()$c` after the condition, since this will throw if `c` hasn't been created within the function, but there are better ways to handle such a set-up.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, it defies my understanding that a variable not declared inside a function takes a value from the global or parent environment. But as Akrun mentioned, it's how R works. And even Gregor Thomas pointed that an object not defined should be NULL, but in this case it is defined outside the function, so that's why I get 17 and not 13 or error. It has been great how you and the people I mention kindly explained how it works, what paths I should take and what pitfalls I should avoid. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice reprex to help demonstrate the role of environments in R as they apply to functions:

```r
var <- 10

f <- function()
{
  cat("Before function's var declared, var is", var, "\n")
  var <- 5
  cat("After function's var declared, var is", var, "\n")
  this_functions_environment <- environment()
  calling_environment <- parent.env(this_functions_environment)
  cat("In the function's environment, var is", this_functions_environment$var)
  cat("\nIn the calling environment, var is", calling_environment$var)
}

f()
#> Before function's var declared, var is 10 
#> After function's var declared, var is 5 
#> In the function's environment, var is 5
#> In the calling environment, var is 10
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>